# Php Codeigniter data share to facebook

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, web, facebook-php-sdk

Is it possible to share a custom data in a Facebook wall without using FB Connect?

I'm currently developing a application using CodeIgniter PHP. I wan't to share some data to the user's facebook wall using his/her email address that the user provided for his personal information in my application.

Is it possible to send data without using FB Connect? If so, can you teach me how?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Facebook libraries in your application. You can't share anything on the wall without user agreement.